# Type of item in pandas DataFrame bug or feature?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a pandas DataFrame

```
df = read_csv("infile.csv")
```

where infile looks something like

```
i1,i2,f1,f2
3,1,0.1,2.0
2,1,0.3,0.5
```

i.e. two columns of integers and one of floats.

If I query this DataFrame with:

```
print type(df["i1"].ix[0])
```

the type is (as I would expect it too be!) np.int64

Whereas if I use:

```
print type(df.ix[0]["i1"])
```

The type is np.float64

Is this correct behaviour or a bug?

I guess that this is because:

```
df.ix[0]
```

creates a series object which ["i1"] then selects from? But still this is annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note yourself, this is indeed expected behaviour because in `df.ix[0]["i1"]` you first create a Series for the first row (so all items are upcasted to float to get one dtype), and only then you take the item with label `"i1"`

The solution is easy: don't use this chained indexing, but combine both look-ups (for row and column) in one indexing call:

```
df.ix[0, "i1"]
```

There are also other good reasons to avoid this chained indexing (getting problems with view/copy): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy